# Link Button to route to the another component is not working in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am implementing a form and download the text input from the form as a PDF. But i am facing issue while implementing the Next and submit button which can route to my PDF component which are having option to download the form. Can anyone please help me here to resolve this :)
Following is my component named "Map" with Next Button which should Route to the PDF component:

```
enter code here

import React , { Component} from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import PDF from './PDF';

const useStyles = (theme) => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: "theme.spacing(8)",
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: 'spacing(1)',
    backgroundColor: 'palette.secondary.main',
    alignItems:'center'
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: 'spacing(3)',
  },
  submit: {
    margin: 'spacing(3, 0, 2)'
  },
});




class Map extends React.Component {
   
    userData;

    constructor (props)  {
        super(props);
        this.onChangefirstName = this.onChangefirstName.bind(this);
        this.onChangelastName = this.onChangelastName.bind(this);
        this.onChangeEmail = this.onChangeEmail.bind(this);
        this.onChangePhone = this.onChangePhone.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        
        this.state = {
            fname: '',
            lname:'',
            email: '',
            phone: '',
            postSubmitted:false
        }
        
    }
    
    // Form event
    onChangefirstName(e) {
        this.setState({ fname: e.target.value})
    }

    onChangelastName(e){
        this.setState({lname: e.target.value})
    }

    onChangeEmail(e){
        this.setState({email: e.target.value})
    }

    onChangePhone(e){
        this.setState({phone: e.target.value})
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()

    }

    //React Lifecycle

    componentDidMount(){
        this.userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        if (localStorage.getItem('user')) {
            this.setState({
                fname: this.userData.fname,
                lname: this.userData.lname,
                email: this.userData.email,
                phone: this.userData.phone
            })
            
        } else {
            this.setState({
                fname: '',
                lname: '',
                email: '',
                phone: ''
            })
            
        }
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(nextState));
    }

    //Validation
    submitPost = e => {
        if (!this.state.fname || !this.state.lname || !this.state.email) {
            alert(" All fields are required")
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            this.setState({
                postSubmitted: true
            });
        }
    }
    render(){

      const {classes} = this.props;
             
        return (

            <>
                { 
                    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
                    <CssBaseline />
                    <div className={classes.paper}><br></br>
                    
                        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                        Tell About Yourself
                        </Typography> <br></br>
                        <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <Grid container spacing={2}>
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                            <TextField
                                autoComplete="fname"
                                name="firstName"
                                variant="outlined"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                id="firstName"
                                label="First Name"
                                autoFocus
                                value={this.state.fname}
                                onChange={this.onChangefirstName}

                            />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                            <TextField
                                variant="outlined"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                id="lastName"
                                label="Last Name"
                                name="lastName"
                                autoComplete="lname"
                                value={this.state.lname}
                                onChange={this.onChangelastName}

                            />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <TextField
                                variant="outlined"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                id="email"
                                label="Email Address"
                                name="email"
                                value={this.state.email}
                                onChange={this.onChangeEmail}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <TextField
                                variant="outlined"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                name="phone"
                                label="Phone Number"
                                type="phone"
                                id="phone"
                                autoComplete="phone"
                                value={this.state.phone}
                                onChange={this.onChangePhone}
                            />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={<Checkbox value="allowExtraEmails" color="primary" /> }
                                label="Your contact details will be shared with TØyen Unlimited"
                                alignItems='row'
                            />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid><br></br>
                        <Button
                            fullWidth
                            variant="contained"
                            color="secondary"
                            className={classes.submit}
                            
                            component={Link}
                            to="/PDF"
                        >
                            Submit and Go to next
                        </Button>
                        
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    </Container> 
                }
            </>
        );
     }
}

export default withStyles(useStyles, {withTheme:true}) (Map)
```

---

Following is my App.js component where i have defined Route property:

```
import './App.css';
import {  makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import About from './Components/About';
import Map from './Components/Map';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import PDF from './Components/PDF';


const styles = makeStyles({
  wrapper: {
    width: "65%",
    margin: "auto" ,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
 
  bigSpace: {
    marginTop:  "5rem"
  },
  littleSpace:  {
    marginTop:  "2.5rem"
  },
  title: {
    color: "#314976",
    font: "Italic"
  }
})


function App() {
  const classes = styles();

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar/>

        <div className={classes.wrapper}>
          <switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home/>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/About">
              <About/>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/Map">
              <Map/>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/PDF" >
              <PDF/>
            </Route>
            
          </switch>
        </div>
      
        <div  className={classes.bigSpace}>
          <Footer/>
        </div>

      </div>
    </Router>

          

  );  
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you're importing and using the `Link` component from Material-UI and ***not*** the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`.

```
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
```

[Material-UI Link](https://material-ui.com/api/link/)

From what I can tell from the Material-UI `Link` component renders a normal anchor tag, i.e. to link out to external resources, not to routes within the app. In other words, the link isn't using the routing context to handle any navigation.

I believe the simplest resolution is to just import the `react-router-dom` `Link` component instead.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Button
  fullWidth
  variant="contained"
  color="secondary"
  className={classes.submit}
  component={Link}
  to="/PDF"
>
  Submit and Go to next
</Button>
```

[image: Edit link-button-to-route-to-the-another-component-is-not-working-in-react-js]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out and now it is working fine after importing Link from react-router-dom.

Comment: @KishanKumar Welcome. I had to test it out first to confirm, so included the sandbox code for you. :) Cheers.

Comment: But there is a problem with this BrowserRouter because when i am refreshing and click on  back button of the browser then the page is going blank :(
Do you have any comment on this?

Comment: @KishanKumar Hi, this sounds like a new and different issue, it would be better to post a new question on SO and include the relevant code and specific issue details. You can ping (2) me here with a link to the question, or in a comment in your new post, and I can take a look. I'd need more details about what "page is going blank" means and would want to see your current code.